# Преобразовать матрицу с двумя столбцами (размерности: N x 2) в две матрицы (каждая размерности: N x 1)

Tags: python, list, список, матрицы

Есть список, например:

```
a = [[3.56677, 1.56567],[4.675753, 3.35311],[118.26811218, 1.15686274],
     [118.26811218, 1.15686274],[118.26811218, 1.15686274]]
```

Необходимо разделить каждый из элементов на два и объединить всё в один список.

Например:

```
b = [[3.56677],[4.675753],[118.26811218],[118.26811218],[118.26811218]]
c = [[1.56567],[3.35311],[1.15686274],[1.15686274],[1.15686274]]
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
b,c = [list(map(lambda z: [z], x)) for x in zip(*a)]

print(b)
# [[3.56677], [4.675753], [118.26811218], [118.26811218], [118.26811218]]

print(c)
# [[1.56567], [3.35311], [1.15686274], [1.15686274], [1.15686274]]
```

---

Решение с использованием модуля Numpy:

```
import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

b,c = np.array(a)[np.newaxis, :].T

print(b)
#[[  3.56677   ]
# [  4.675753  ]
# [118.26811218]
# [118.26811218]
# [118.26811218]]

print(b.tolist())
#[[3.56677], [4.675753], [118.26811218], [118.26811218], [118.26811218]]

print(c.tolist())
#[[1.56567], [3.35311], [1.15686274], [1.15686274], [1.15686274]]
```

Comment: Красиво с list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
a = [[3.56677, 1.56567],[4.675753, 3.35311],[118.26811218, 1.15686274], [118.26811218, 
1.15686274],[118.26811218, 1.15686274]]

newlist=[]
for elem in list(it.chain.from_iterable(a)):
    newlist.append([elem])
print(newlist)
```

На выходе:

```
[[3.56677], [1.56567], [4.675753], [3.35311], [118.26811218], [1.15686274], [118.26811218], [1.15686274], [118.26811218], [1.15686274]]
```